# Exception datetime in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, date, exception

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

My code:

```
 string sqlthem = "INSERT INTO Infosp1 VALUES (@khach,@sp,@sl,@gia,@tg)";
        string sqlconvert = "select CONVERT(varchar(20),[Tg], 103) from Infosp1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlthem, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Khach", cbbtenkh.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sp", cbbmahang.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sl", cbbsl.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gia", cbbgia.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tg", datetg.Text);           
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It appear at `.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Pls

Comment: You really should make sure the types of the parameters match the type of the columns in your DB and to do that you should parse `string` values to `DateTime` in the code first.  Also consider [not using `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Could you show example value passed in `datetg` variable?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Khach", cbbtenkh.Text)`;

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal No, it will add the @ if you don't.

Comment: how to do add 'datetimepicker' on form into sql by `cmd`, pls!

Comment: i tried to use `CAST('"+datetg.Text+"' AS datetime)` 
@juharr

Comment: @Igor let me see it. Thanks!

Comment: No you need to do something like `cmd.Parameters.Add("Tg", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(datetg.Text);`.  If the `Parse` fails then use `ParseExact` with whatever date formats are being entered.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, moreover stop using `AddWithValue()` rather chose to use `Add()` overload

Comment: @Rahul: Any solid reason? or just a hunch.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, haven't you read this http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific!

Comment: @Rahul: No. Will read it in spare time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have datetime fields you need to convert your parameter to datetime. If you want this to perform conversion, it won't work because you're not executing this query:

```
string sqlconvert = "select CONVERT(varchar(20),[Tg], 103) from Infosp1";
```

you try to insert a string which is not converted, and thus might have incorrect format.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tg", datetg.Text);
```

Try creating sql parameter defining its datatype like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Tg", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(datetg.Text);
```

*Ideally you should have CultureInfo somewhere to parse instead*

...or call the conversion in sql script, like so:

```
string sqlthem = @"declare @dt datetime
    select @dt = CONVERT(varchar(20), @tg, 103)
    INSERT INTO Infosp1 VALUES (@khach,@sp,@sl,@gia,@dt)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaining. I tried and it appear this exception :`Additional information: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: try using 
     DateTime tg;
     TryParse(datetg.Text, tg out);

     cmd.Parameters.Add("Tg", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = tg;

Comment: You need to check which values were rejected by parse (TryParse should return false if it failed).